# VictoryNative - Adding stripped pattern in the bars for the bar chart

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I am using VictoryJS in React Native and I am using bar charts. However, for one of my bar charts, I want to add a striped pattern inside the solid bar.

My current implementation is using the `dataComponent` prop to render a View with just the background color and inside it an image containing the striped pattern. However, it's making my customTooltips jitter.

```
 <View
   style={{
     width: barWidth,
     height: y,
     backgroundColor: bgColor,
     overflow: "hidden",
   }}
 >
    <Image source={stripePattern} resizeMode="cover" /> ...
```

Any tips would be great